# Размывается текст при переходе

Tags: html, css

Ну не думал что текст будет размываться когда будет находиться неподвижно.
Самое забавное это видно в Google Chrome, но не видно в Firefox.

```css
.main{
  position:relative;
  background:rgb(255, 87, 34);
  width:100px;
  height:30px;
  border-radius:5px;
  overflow:hidden;
  font:normal 15px sans-serif;
}
.main .blink{
  position:absolute;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  transform:translateX(-85px);
  pointer-events:none;
  transition:transform 0.7s ease;
}
.main:hover .blink{
  transform:translateX(85px);
}
.main .blink .lensflare{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background:rgba(255,255,255,0.15);
  transform:rotate(135deg);
}
.main .text{
  position:relative;
  float:left;
  color:white;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
  pointer-events:none;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="blink">
    <div class="lensflare"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="text">Hello</div>
</div>
```

Как сделать так чтобы влияние на текст не было?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/14677490/6275986

Comment: @Other ничего из тех советов не помогает

Answer (score 1):

```css
.main{
  position:relative;
  background:rgb(255, 87, 34);
  width:100px;
  height:30px;
  border-radius:5px;
  overflow:hidden;
  font:normal 15px sans-serif;
}
.main .blink{
  position:absolute;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  transform:translateX(-85px);
  pointer-events:none;
  transition:transform 0.7s ease;
}
.main:hover .blink{
  transform:translateX(85px);
}
.main .blink .lensflare{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background:rgba(255,255,255,0.15);
  transform:rotate(135deg);
}
.main .text{
  position:relative;
  color:white;
  pointer-events:none;
  text-align: center;
  top: 6px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="blink">
    <div class="lensflare"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="text" >Hello</div>
</div>
```

а вообще то трансформирование - это экспериментальная технология. ее использование не гарантирует стабильной работы.

Comment: Собственно вы убрали `transform:translate(-50%,-50%);`. Так как вы написали решение то все корректно и о нем я знал. Единственный момент я хотел бы не отказываться от `transform:translate(-50%,-50%);`

Comment: @MaximPro дело в том что `chrome` некорректно рендерит текст поверх трансформируемого элемента. Что бы в этом убедится вы можете вынести его из контейнера `main` и наложить его отрицательным значением `top` и даже это вам не поможет. Если вы внимательно приглядитесь то и мой вариант ответа не лешон этого недостатка, просто этот глюк стал едва заметным но все равно сохраняется.

Comment: Да, глюк по факту остается, но он стал не таким броским как у меня в примере.